# Cordova on iOS - AJAX call fails with {"readyState":"0", "responseText":"", "status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova, readystate

I updated cordova yesterday and added the iOS platform (cordova-ios@^6.1.0). I am trying to make an AJAX call via the XCODE simulator and it is failing with the following output:

```
{"readyState":"0", "responseText":"", "status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

I installed cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin and added the following lines to config.xml:

```
<access origin="http://*" />
<access origin="https://*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

I have also added the following meta tag to the page:

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src *">

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was with the server being called, a PHP API.

Adding the following allowed the AJAX request to succeed:

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

?>
```